# Use function empty with <h4>, glyphicon-delete but svg stay in Meteor/JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, meteor

I use C3.js for generate many Graph. Each graph is a zone where I add title, and glyphicon (remove my graph).

In the first I have a zone with `border-style: dashed;` when I click I generate a new graph, the css change in `border-style: solid;` .

I'd like when I click on glyphicon my css change in default and my graph is empty or hidden?

```
<template name="graph2">
    <div class="zone background" id="zone-0_2" >
      <svg class ="insert" id="graphItem0_2" with="300" height="300"></svg>
      <!-- {{> conversion1 }}  --> 
      <p class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog" id="form"></p>    
    </div>

</template>
```

when I configure my graph with a form I add my glyphicon with the title.

```
    var concat_title_close = "close" + nameGraph;
    if ($(Session.get("zone" )).find("h4").length == 0) {
      $(Session.get("zone" )).prepend("<h4 id='"+concat+ "'><center>" + titre + "</center></h4>");
      $(Session.get("zone" )).find("h4").prepend('<p class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove close" id="' + concat_title_close + '" style="float:right;  margin-right: 20px;" ></p>');
    }else{
      $($(Session.get("zone" )).find("h4")).remove('h4');
      $(Session.get("zone" )).prepend("<h4 id='"+concat+"'><center>" + titre + "</center></h4>");
      $(Session.get("zone" )).find("h4").prepend('<p class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove close" id="' + concat_title_close + '" style="float:right;  margin-right: 20px;"></p>');
    }
```

when I click on glyphicon `.close` I have this code :

```
'click .close': function(event, template){
    console.log(event.currentTarget);
    //console.log(template);
    $(event.currentTarget.parentNode).empty();
    $(event.currentTarget.parentNode).css({'background-image':'url("/ressources/plus.png")', 'color': 'grey' , 'border-style' : 'dashed'});     
  }
```

This code delete the title and the glyphicon but the graph stay, the css don't change.

Have you a idea to delete the graph?